# Function Won't Recurse

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to make a 'web player' that plays music when you click the play button, and displays how far along you are in the track  on a bar. I have made a function that plays the audio and checks how far along the track you are to set the width of the playback bar, but for the life of me i can't get it to recurse. I know the function works, because the playback bar jumps to the correct position when you click the play button, but i cant seem to automate it. Here is the code:

```
function play(x) { 
  var audio = document.getElementById(x);
  audio.play(); 
  var progress = audio.currentTime;
  var duration = audio.duration;
  var percent = progress/duration;
  var width = percent*100;
  var progbar = document.getElementById("play-line-elapsed");
  var width = width + "%";
  progbar.style.width = width;
  setTimeout(play("Bring-Out-Yer-Dead"), 5000);
}
const createClock = setInterval(play, 100);
```

I have tried while loops, do while loops, setTimeout and finally setInterval so far. I am also a complete beginner to javascript, so it'll probably be completely obvious when someone points it out to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: `setTimeout(()=>play("Bring-Out-Yer-Dead"), 5000);`  you're passing undefined to setTimeout, wrap it in a function to pass the function.  also setInterval is calling play with x=undefined

Comment: In addition to using `setTimeout` correctly, you are currently mixing the concerns of starting the player (`audio.play()`) with updating the progress bar. These are two separate operations. You should look into using the `progress` event of the player to update your progress bar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/progress_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that should work

```
function play(x) { 
  var audio = document.getElementById(x);
  audio.play(); 
  var progress = audio.currentTime;
  var duration = audio.duration;
  var percent = progress/duration;
  var width = percent*100;
  var progbar = document.getElementById("play-line-elapsed");
  var width = width + "%";
  progbar.style.width = width;
  setTimeout(function () {play("Bring-Out-Yer-Dead")}, 5000);
}
const createClock = setTimeout(function () {play("Bring-Out-Yer-Dead")}, 100);
```

What you did was to create an interval that calls `play` every 0.1 seconds, without any arguments. I suppose that wouldn't work as the function requires an argument.

Your `setTimeout` at the end of `play` wouldn't work too, because you're just calling it. You should provide a function object (not very correct word, but you get it) to setTimout, not calling it. The way you did it is to call `play` and give its return value (which is `undefined`) to `setTimout`, which makes `setTimeout` do nothing.

The corrected code creates a timeout that calls `play` after 0.1 seconds, then `play` continues to call itself every 5 seconds.

You have to provide a 0 arity function to `setTimeout/setInterval`, meaning a function that accepts no arguments. I used an anonymous function for that, but you could write another function with no arguments and use it there.

But I think you would be better off using events. I haven't tested any of these, but these events seem promising for what you are trying to do.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondurationchange.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onplaying.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onplay.asp

Comment: Thanks :) that works. Ill have a look at events though, that does seem promising